# Why Tasks gives different Linq Sum() outputs?

Tags: c#, linq

It's pretty strange in below code, It gives me different `Sum` of one Enumerable Range.

Why?

```
var num = Enumerable.Range(-10000, 20001).Reverse().ToList();

Action task1 = () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum 2: {num.Sum()}");
};

Action task2 = () =>
{
    num.Sort();
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum 3: { num.Sum()}");
};

Parallel.Invoke(task1, task2);

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Sum 2: 0
Sum 3: 0
```

**Outputs:**

```
Sum 2: 94646670
Sum 3: 0
```

Comment: `task2` is sorting the `num` `List<T>` **in place** while `task1` is iterating over it. Thus the behaviour you are seeing is expected. To fix, ensure that `task1` and `task2` are not sharing state (i.e. not sharing `num`).

Comment: @KhawajaAsim the only part modifying the *num* is *Sort*. What else can be?

Comment: _"do you think sorting effects Sum?"_ - In combination with Parallel.Invoke: yes, of course.

Comment: @KhawajaaAsim Let's say I have 10 kids. You ask what their names are. I put them in a line. I read them left to write. They are called Sally, Bob, Charlie, Deirdre etc etc. Then I do the same thing, but I do it **while the kids keep swapping places**. Now they are called Sally, Bob, Charlie, Sally etc etc. That is the same thing happening when your `Sum` call is iterating over the list.

Comment: @mjwills that's nice explanation, thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you run parallel tasks, there is some risk of both tasks accessing the same memory at the same time (assuming you don't have a SynchronizationContext that serializes the tasks, or a `lock` to gate access).  In this case one thread is iterating over the list while the other is moving around the elements in that list. So the sum might contain the some elements more than once, and others not at all. In some cases (not in this example) a thread might even read *part* of an element, e.g. if it the size of an element exceeds the width of atomic reads (32 bits aligned, on Wintel).

To prove this is the reason, try creating a second list and giving it to the second task, like this:

```
var num1 = Enumerable.Range(-10000, 20001).Reverse().ToList();
var num2 = Enumerable.Range(-10000, 20001).Reverse().ToList();

Action task1 = () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sum 2: {0}", num1.Sum());
};

Action task2 = () =>
{
    num2.Sort();
    Console.WriteLine("Sum 3: {0}", num2.Sum());
};

Parallel.Invoke(task1, task2);
```

If you do it that way, you will always get `0` for both answers.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer, and I was just asking why is that so. thank you

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is not thread safe so `Parallel.Invoke` is happening on different threads. Your answer is non-deterministic since on thread calling `num.Sort()` is modifying the list while another is enumerating it.

Comment: kinda surprised that he didn't get collection modified exception

Comment: @Steve That would be more likely to occur if, for example, the size of the list changed.

Answer (score 0):

`Sort` and `Sum` aren't atomic... one thread is calculating the sum, while sort is moving the numbers around so `Sum` is going to count some numbers twice, and some numbers will be skipped entirely. You'll notice that you actually get different results every time you run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sort mutates state so use `OrderBy(x => x)` instead of the `Sort()` and you will get predictable sorting results.